# What makes luxury cars and super cars so expensive?

Tags: car

I have always wondered why these type of cars cost so much,
is it really just a social status thing or are they made of extremely expensive materials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both, plus the fact that many are basically hand-made unlike the cheap cars built by robots that most of us have.

Just the radiator grille on a Rolls-Royce was apparently 200 hours work...

When you look at the bodywork, the interior etc the craftsmanship is stunning but it costs a huge amount.

The advent of mass production brought the price of manufacture down (see Henry Ford... any colour you like as long as it is black..) giving rise to cheap transport to the masses and traffic jams / congestion and, of course, pollution.

Comment: And what if the exterior design was not so appealing, or simply put - an ugly design, same materials inside, same technology, but just an ugly looking car, would it still be worth as much? (having put so many hours of work in it and all)

Comment: Simple answer : beauty is in the eye of the beholder...

Comment: Of course the other version is "beauty is in the eye of the beer holder"....

Comment: In that case, they should serve beer at every dealership